# I can't catch interested ID from inserted and use it in exec of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I can't execute a procedure in my trigger with a parameter from the `inserted` pseudo table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Restauracja]
ON [dbo].[RezerwacjaPozycje] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID INT;

    SELECT IdReservation = @ID 
    FROM INSERTED       

    EXEC SumOrderPositions @ID;
END
```

If I change @id to f.e. 9. it correctly updates what I want for `IdReservation` number 9.

Comment: Do you get an error?  What is the problem?

Comment: There's no any type of error. It just dont change anything like never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting only one row, you can simply do the assignment in the correct order:

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID  int;
    SELECT @ID = IdReservation
    FROM INSERTED;    

    EXEC SumOrderPositions @ID;
END;
```

However, this is a bug waiting to happen.  Instead, you may want to use a cursor, loop through the rows in `inserted` using some other mechanism, or check that there is only one row in `inserted`.  I'm not sure the exactly logic that you want.

Comment: wow, it worked. 
But i can't see much difference between

DECLARE @ID  int;
Select IdReservation=@ID FROM INSERTED  

And your working solution :D.

Comment: @WexusNexus The difference is your assignment is backwards `IdReservation=@ID` is not the same as `@ID=IdReservation`

Comment: @WexusNexus and do take note that this is very bad coding practice, because it assumes you will only ever get a single row in your `inserted` pseudo-table. So if multiple rows are every updated in the future you will only process one of them.